# Selenium - Taking full-page mobile screenshots via BrowserStack

Tags: c#, selenium, mobile, browserstack

I’ve created a tool to take full-page screenshots on a list of URLs on a number of desktop and device configs. On desktop, this all works swimmingly and I get full-page screenshots back with no issue on all browsers and OS versions.

The problem comes when trying to do this on mobile devices, which I'm guessing is due to the pixel ratio of the devices I’m running on.

My method takes the total height and width of the page, as well as the height and width of the viewport, and basically takes images of the viewport, scrolls where necessary, then at the end, stitches all this together into a single image.

However, with the pixel ratio, which I’m retrieving via JavaScript, the screenshots are never captured properly and don’t scroll correctly and/or don’t capture the entirety of the page. Widthwise it’s ok, it’s always height. It's like it's calculating the scrolling incorrectly

I’m staggered by the fact that I can’t find any posts anywhere online with people who have had the same or similar issues. So either I’m over complicating it and it’s so trivial that it’s never required a post, or this is way harder than I think and people aren’t doing it for good reason

If anyone has any thoughts or ideas, they would be very much appreciated

Thanks!

The code for this method is as follows:

```
public Image GetEntireScreenshot(ArrayList hiddenElementListAfterFirstViewport = null, bool isMobile = false)
        {
            var pixelRatio = 1; 
            if (isMobile) pixelRatio = (int) (long) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return window.devicePixelRatio");

            // Size of page
            var totalWidth = Convert.ToInt32((int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.offsetWidth") * pixelRatio);
            var totalHeight = Convert.ToInt32((int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return  document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight") * pixelRatio);

            // Size of the viewport
            var viewportWidth = Convert.ToInt32((int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.clientWidth") * pixelRatio);
            var viewportHeight = Convert.ToInt32((int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight") * pixelRatio);


            var screenshot = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 0)");

            if (hiddenElementListAfterFirstViewport != null)
            {
                foreach (string hiddenElementXPath in hiddenElementListAfterFirstViewport)
                {
                    IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(hiddenElementXPath));
                    foreach (var element in elements)
                    {
                        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", element);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (totalWidth <= viewportWidth && totalHeight <= viewportHeight) return ScreenshotToImage(screenshot.GetScreenshot());

            var rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

            // Loop until the totalHeight is reached
            for (var y = 0; y < totalHeight; y += viewportHeight)
            {
                var newHeight = viewportHeight;

                // Fix if the height of the element is too big
                if (y + viewportHeight > totalHeight) newHeight = totalHeight - y;

                // Loop until the totalWidth is reached
                for (var x = 0; x < totalWidth; x += viewportWidth)
                {
                    var newWidth = viewportWidth;
                    // Fix if the Width of the Element is too big
                    if (x + viewportWidth > totalWidth) newWidth = totalWidth - x;

                    // Create and add the Rectangle
                    rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, newWidth, newHeight));
                }
            }

            var stitchedImage = new Bitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight);
            var previous = Rectangle.Empty;
            foreach (var rectangle in rectangles)
            {
                // Calculate scrolling (if needed)
                if (previous != Rectangle.Empty) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy({rectangle.Right - previous.Right}, {rectangle.Bottom - previous.Bottom})");

                // Calculate the source Rectangle
                var sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(viewportWidth - rectangle.Width,
                                                    viewportHeight - rectangle.Height,
                                                    rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);

                // Copy the Image
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(stitchedImage))
                {
                    graphics.DrawImage(ScreenshotToImage(screenshot.GetScreenshot()), rectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                previous = rectangle;
            }
            return stitchedImage;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the issue to the problem, posting here on the off chance someone who has the same problem sees this post:

The issue was with the scrolling part of the code:

```
if (previous != Rectangle.Empty) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy({rectangle.Right - previous.Right}, {rectangle.Bottom - previous.Bottom})");
```

I was scrolling by values previously multiplied by the pixel ratio amount, which meant they were too much given the scroll X and Y values aren't affected by the pixel ratio of the device.

So instead, the code should be:

```
if (previous != Rectangle.Empty) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy({(rectangle.Right - previous.Right) / pixelRatio}, {(rectangle.Bottom - previous.Bottom) / pixelRatio})");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like ShutterBug to capture full-page screenshots on mobile devices, http://automationtesting.in/take-full-page-screenshot-using-shutterbug/